# Comparing and validating a date input with a stored date

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a textbox where a user is inputting a date (line date). If the date they input is greater than a related date (header date) I want asp.net to throw an error. I am trying to do this dynamicly but am getting an error saying cannot convert data type to "date".

ASP.NET CODE (WHERE I AM DOING THE VALIDATION):

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="valBidContractEnd" runat="server" Text="*" 
                            ErrorMessage="Error: Bid End Date must be after the effective date of the bid." Type="Date"
                            Display="Dynamic" ValueToCompare='<%#Eval("ContractEndDate", "{0:d}")%>' ControlToValidate="dtEnd" Operator="GreaterThanEqual"/>
```

Where I am reading the date it is comparing to, this is called in page load:

```
private void LoadContractInfo()
{
    if (QSContractID.HasValue)
    {
        ContractData data = new ContractData();
        using (IDataReader r = data.ContractGet(QSContractID.Value))
        {
            if (r.Read())
            {
                lblContractName.Text = r["ContractName"].ToStr();
                lblContractRefNo.Text = r["ContractRefNo"].ToStr();
                r["ContractEndDate"].ToDateTime();
            }
        }
    }
}
```